# Mysql query : how to calculate statistic growth rate between two period per category

Tags: mysql, sql

From this table of dates and categories inputs :

[image]

I'd like to get these folowing table, showing number of rows per category for each first and second quarter, and the growth of number of rows between second and first quarter, in value, and in percentage - which is a simple statistic table type that could be met to get the number of item per period of time and its growth.

[image]

What would be the sql query to get this table ?

Here is the SQL code to create the sql table, in order you to reproduce the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a_test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_row` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Here is the sql code to fill the table with the data :

```
INSERT INTO `table_a_test_table` (`date_row`, `category`) 
VALUES 
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-02-02 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-03-08 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-02-06 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-04-07 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-05-21 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-06-07 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-06-08 00:00:00', 'B')
;
```

I've tried the following sql code, to get the result table, but I do not know where I should, and how I should introduce the `category` field in order to get a group by output.

```
SELECT 
    nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows AS `number of row in q1`,
    nb_rows_q2.nb_of_rows AS `number of row in q2`,
    ((nb_rows_q2.nb_of_rows - nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows)/nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows)*100 AS `growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1`
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(id) AS nb_of_rows
    FROM    table_a_test_table
    WHERE 
        date_row >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
        AND date_row < '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
    ) AS nb_rows_q1,
    (
    SELECT  COUNT(id) AS nb_of_rows
    FROM    table_a_test_table
    WHERE 
            date_row >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' 
        AND date_row < '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
    ) AS nb_rows_q2 
;
```

The above code, returns the following :

[image]

So now, I'd like t place the `category` field into the code. But I do not knwo how to do it.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to aggregate by categories within your subqueries first so you wouldn't lose the category details in the final projection. See a sample working fiddle and results below:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a_test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_row` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table_a_test_table` (`date_row`, `category`) 
VALUES 
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-02-02 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-03-08 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-02-06 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-04-07 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-05-21 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-06-07 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-06-08 00:00:00', 'B')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    nb_rows_q1.category,
    nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows AS `number of row in q1`,
    nb_rows_q2.nb_of_rows AS `number of row in q2`,
    (nb_rows_q2.nb_of_rows - nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows) as `variation of nb of row q2 vs q1`,
    ((nb_rows_q2.nb_of_rows - nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows)/nb_rows_q1.nb_of_rows)*100 AS `growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1`
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  category, COUNT(id) AS nb_of_rows
    FROM    table_a_test_table
    WHERE 
        date_row >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
        AND date_row < '2020-04-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY category
    ) AS nb_rows_q1 
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT  category,COUNT(id) AS nb_of_rows
    FROM    table_a_test_table
    WHERE 
            date_row >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' 
        AND date_row < '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY category
    ) AS nb_rows_q2  ON nb_rows_q1.category = nb_rows_q2.category
;
```

| category | number of row in q1 | number of row in q2 | variation of nb of row q2 vs q1 | growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | -1 | -50.0000 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 1 | 100.0000 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.0000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fERUrRScYkNS1Uve6svYUW/1)

### Update 1

Another approach has been included below where the aggregation has been done with the help of a case expression. I have also added to your test data, `D` only  in `q2`, `E` only in `q1` and `F` neither in `q1` or `q2`. This approach includes categories in either quarter. I also added a case expression for categories that are new or only occurring in quarter 2 that would have the growth rate as `null`. This is up to you whether you would like the growth rate returned as `null` or a default value, I included `100`

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a_test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_row` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `table_a_test_table` (`date_row`, `category`) 
VALUES 
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-02-02 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-03-08 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-02-06 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-04-07 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-05-21 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2020-06-07 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2020-06-08 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2020-06-08 00:00:00', 'D'),
    ('2020-01-03 00:00:00', 'E'),
    ('2019-01-03 00:00:00', 'F')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    category,
    q1 as `number of row in q1`,
    q2 as `number of row in q2`,
    (q2 - q1) as `variation of nb of row q2 vs q1`,
    CASE 
        WHEN q1=0 THEN 100.0 
        ELSE((q2-q1)/q1)*100
    END as `growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1`
FROM (
SELECT
    category,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_row < '2020-04-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as q1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_row >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as q2
FROM
    table_a_test_table
WHERE 
    date_row BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    category
) summary;
```

| category | number of row in q1 | number of row in q2 | variation of nb of row q2 vs q1 | growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | -1 | -50.0000 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 1 | 100.0000 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.0000 |
| D | 0 | 1 | 1 | 100.0 |
| E | 1 | 0 | -1 | -100.0000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fERUrRScYkNS1Uve6svYUW/5)

Feel free to experiment with other filtering options. For example, if you would like to filter out entries like `D` or `E` that exist in only one quarter you may consider adding a `WHERE` clause similar to `WHERE q1 > 0 and q2 > 0;` as shown below:

```
SELECT 
    category,
    q1 as `number of row in q1`,
    q2 as `number of row in q2`,
    (q2 - q1) as `variation of nb of row q2 vs q1`,
    CASE 
        WHEN q1=0 THEN 100.0 
        ELSE((q2-q1)/q1)*100
    END as `growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1`
FROM (
SELECT
    category,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_row < '2020-04-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as q1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_row >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as q2
FROM
    table_a_test_table
WHERE 
    date_row BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    category
) summary
WHERE q1 > 0 and q2 > 0;
```

| category | number of row in q1 | number of row in q2 | variation of nb of row q2 vs q1 | growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | -1 | -50.0000 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 1 | 100.0000 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.0000 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fERUrRScYkNS1Uve6svYUW/6)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Using INNER JOIN will not return categories which have an entry only in one of quarter - ie: category with entry in q1 but not in q2, and category with entry in q2 but not in q1 - , won't it ? What would be such a code with `UNION` instead `INNER JOIN` ? I have difficulty to try to make a version with an UNION to the code.

Comment: While the `UNION` is possible for your solution, you would still need to aggregate using a group by. I have updated my answer with another option, sample data and fiddles. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot @ggordon. Your updates with another option, helps me a lot for both configuration with or without pairing between q1 and q2.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need one subquery and don't need `JOIN` at all. Something like this:

```
SELECT category, 
       q1 AS `number of row in q1`, 
       q2 AS `number of row in q2`, 
       q2-q1 AS `variation of nb of q2 vs q1`, 
       ((q2-q1)/q1)*100 AS `growth nb of rows between q2 vs q1`
FROM
(SELECT category,
        SUM(CASE WHEN date_row >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00' 
                  AND date_row < '2020-04-01 00:00:00' 
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'q1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN date_row >= '2020-04-01 00:00:00' 
                  AND date_row < '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'q2'
FROM table_a_test_table
GROUP BY category) A;
```

The base query there I use `SUM()` with `CASE` expression. The condition in both of your previous subqueries I used as the condition in the `CASE` expression followed by a `GROUP BY` on `category` column. And as you can see, I've assigned with short abbreviations for `q1` and `q2` and instead of doing all the calculation for differences and percentage in the same line of `SELECT`, I turned the query into a subquery and do the calculation outside. This, in my opinion, made the query much more readable.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90c229c37f33241ac9dc30ff01abbf3c)

Comment: This code returns all entries of category, including `NULL` category entries that could exist for one quarter of for the other - ie, it will returns entries of category which have an entry in q1 but not in q2, and entries of category which have an entry in q2 but not in q1 - does it ? Is it possible to get a similar code excluding any category which has no entry in q1 or in q2 ?

Comment: Let's see this in a fiddle, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c7fe3f043481a60b20392ee79f1a7c60 . I've added `D` & `E` in the data and both don't have pairs that existed in either `q1` or `q2`. If I understand what you mean, you don't want to see `D` & `E` because there are no pairings for them correct?

Comment: "you don't want to see D & E because there are no pairings for them, correct?" When your previous code shows only pairings, So it could be also interesting to get also an other code showing also no-parings,  giving a result similar to ggordon code ? I imagine a `WHERE ... IS NOT NULL` will work. But how to place it ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get what you mean.. perhaps you could confirm it through this fiddle? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65c6a96d88b8748e52de901223a366f7